# How can I eliminate Google Fonts from Google AdSense code?

Tags: adsense

I use **Google AdSense** in a website. Google AdSense uses **Google Fonts**. Google Fonts are subject to warnings in Europe because they transmit the IP. How can I eliminate Google Fonts from Google AdSense code ?

Google AdSense code gives you following code snippet:

```html
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Display Ad horizontally -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:block"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
         data-ad-slot="47945XXXXX"
         data-ad-format="auto"
         data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
    <script>
         (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
```

What I found:

I can change the font for some ad blocks in the Google Adsense Dashboard. But that's a Google font again...
You cannot change the font for other ad units (e.g. for display ads).

So, I don't know how to get Google Fonts out of Google AdSense code.

Is it possible to solve the problem with a separate code? But how it looks?

Thank you for the interest.
dirk